# failure to static build glib for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have bashed my head for 3 days now with this failure.  So, I am asking for your help.

I built the pre-requisite libs: libffi.a & proxy-libintl.

The configure step runs to completion.  I used this question as my guide [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638594/how-to-build-glib-for-ios).

These are the errors I get:

```
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=missing-prototypes -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=init-self -Werror=format-security -Werror=format=2 -Werror=missing-include-dirs -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/usr/lib -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -g  -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/usr/lib -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -Wl,-iphoneos_version_min,7.0 -o gobject-query gobject-query.o ./libgobject-2.0.la ../glib/libglib-2.0.la -lintl
```

libtool: link: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=missing-prototypes -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=init-self -Werror=format-security -Werror=format=2 -Werror=missing-include-dirs -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/usr/lib -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -g -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -Wl,-iphoneos_version_min -Wl,7.0 -o gobject-query gobject-query.o  -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/usr/lib ./.libs/libgobject-2.0.a -L/Users/maat/Projects/PrebuiltCustomFrameworks/libffi /Users/maat/Projects/QEMU/libsForiOS/glib-2.40.0/src/glib/.libs/libglib-2.0.a -l/Users/maat/Projects/PrebuiltCustomFrameworks/libffi/libffi.a ../glib/.libs/libglib-2.0.a -liconv -lintl
ld: library not found for -l/Users/homey/Projects/PrebuiltCustomFrameworks/libffi/libffi.a
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I know that this echo is not real because an ls on the path gives me this:

Minis-Mac:src homey $ ls -l /Users/homey/Projects/PrebuiltCustomFrameworks/libffi/libffi.a
-rw-r--r--  1 homey  501  107596 May 15 08:03 /Users/homey/Projects/PrebuiltCustomFrameworks/libffi/libffi.a

Any suggestions?

Comment: And what does `lipo -info /Users/homey/Projects/PrebuiltCustomFrameworks/libffi/libffi.a` produce?

Comment: Architectures in the fat file: /Users/homey/Projects/PrebuiltCustomFrameworks/libffi/libffi.a are: armv7 armv7s i386