# glib build for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, glib, meson-build

I am trying to compile and build glib for iOS platform (require glib static library). I referred below link for that:
[How to build GLib for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638594/how-to-build-glib-for-ios)

But the latest version of glib does not have ./configure, due to which script is failing. I tried through brew, but it does not have required architecture version and does not provide static library.

As per GLIB building webpage, meson builds are used to compile glib (I am not good with that). I tried to do cross compile but its got failed (may be due to wrong content)
https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.64/glib-building.html
https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.64/glib-cross-compiling.html

Finally I tried to compile the glib source code on xcode, based on meson build file. I am able to compile glib and gobject code, but getting errors when linking those libraries to my source code. So I am not sure whether I have used all dependencies while compiling, since I am not good in meson builds.

Is there any reference link where I can build the static library of glib for iOS for all architectures ie armv7, armv7s and arm64.

Comment: Have you found the solution to this problem?
If yes please answer your own question because it is for sure not only the both of us who are trying to do this